# Multiple Alignments Inside Button

Tags: vb.net, button

Can you make a single string, within the same button, have different alignments?

For example: `dim String1 = "A B C D E F"`

A - would be in the top left corner B-in the middle top.....
[image]

Comment: Not exactly sure what "different lines of code have different alignments" means...can you give a little more detail?

Comment: Look at the picture, A-needs to be aligned to top left corner, but F-needs to be aligned to bottom right

Comment: No.  A Button only has one text property and it is `String` not `String()`.  You could maybe make do with a `Bitmap`.  Or a subclassed version maybe

Comment: @Dmandy sorry, misunderstood what you wanted...text in different positions of a button is an entirely different thing than "lines of code". as Plutonix said, not possible (although you might be able to find a custom control online?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create labels and set the parents of the label to be that button
*Remember that the position of the label is now relative to the button

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
lblA.text="A"
lblA.Parent=Button1 
lblA.Location = New Size(0,0)
lblB.Text = "B"
lblB.Parent = Button1
lblB.Location = New Size(Button1.width/2,0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible unfortunately, but one way this could be accomplished is by creating an image and assigning it to the button as a `BackgroundImage`.

From this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Ensure to set the properties of your `Button` correctly (aka, remove button text).